# How to not to highlight navigation drawer indicator when pressed

Tags: android, navigation, styles, indicator, drawer

Is there a way to not to highlight the navigation drawer indicator and the logo when pressed. I use:

`<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>`.

I performed this action for the actionbar items with in my styles.xml:

`<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@android:color/transparent</item>`

And it's working properly, but it makes no effect for the indicator+logo .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this in your theme :

```
<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
```